# I can't fix this bug in my reverseStack function

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, stack

```
stack *InsertAtBottom(int n, stack *ptr)
{
    if (isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        push(n, ptr);
        return ptr;
    }
    int tempEle = peek(ptr);
    pop(ptr);
    ptr = InsertAtBottom(tempEle, ptr);
    push(tempEle, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

stack *ReverseStack(stack *ptr)
{
    if (!isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        int n =  peek(ptr);
        pop(ptr);
        ReverseStack(ptr);
        ptr = InsertAtBottom(n, ptr);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

This is my C code for reversing a stack. There is this bug I am trying to fix but not able to figure out what's wrong. If you run the code you will see it's not reversing the stack but replacing all elements with first element. I have checked stack ADTs thoroughly and they are fine.

I am trying to reverse an integer stack.

Comment: `insertAtBottom()` doesn't insert `n` when the stack isn't empty.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] including a simple example of input and expected output.